# Strange value when reading from binary file with fread() in C

Tags: c, linux, fwrite, fread

I have an issue that I can't solve...

I used `fwrite` to write an `int` value (among other values that come from a `struct`) into a file that I've opened using `fopen(file, "wb");`

This worked fine, and when I view the contents of the file, I can see the `HEX` value of the `int` that I've "written" (and all the other values as well).

Next, I try to read the file. So, I open the file using `fopen(file, "rb");` and start reading it using `fread`. The first `int` value is read correctly (e.g. 7) and all the other values after it - which belong to the first `struct` that I've written.

I then try to read the next `struct` and when I try to read the first `int` value, I receive a very strange number (e.g. 1140850688) but it should be 39 instead.

So the question is: Why is this happening? And how can I solve it?

My `struct` looks like this:

```
struct a {
    int a1;
    char* a2;
    struct b* a3;
    unsigned char a4; 
    int a5;
    char* a6; 
}
```

And the `fread` call looks like this: `fread(&(tmpA->a1), sizeof(int), 1, file);`

EDIT:

The `fwrite` part:

```
fwrite(&(tmpA->a1), sizeof(int), 1, file);
fwrite(tmpA->a2, sizeof(char), strlen(tmpA->a2), file);
fwrite(tmpA->a3, sizeof(struct b), 1, file);
fwrite(&(tmpA->a4), sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
fwrite(&(tmpA->a5), sizeof(int), 1, file);
fwrite(tmpA->a6, sizeof(char), strlen(tmpA->a6), file);
```

The `fread` is almost the same.

Comment: Could you post the complete `fwrite` and `fread` parts of your program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your problem is on this line

```
fwrite(tmpA->a3, sizeof(struct b), 1, file);
```

where you are writing a `struct`. This struct will have padding bytes, as per [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) which will offset the rest of your data. You will likely have to come up with a better way of writing that struct to memory. [This page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/) provides additional explanation.

You can check to see if this is indeed the problem by checking if `a4` has the value you expect, or by comparing the size of the entire struct versus the sum of the sizes of its members.

Also, these lines look dangerous:

```
fwrite(tmpA->a2, sizeof(char), strlen(tmpA->a2), file);
fwrite(tmpA->a6, sizeof(char), strlen(tmpA->a6), file);
```

they say that the length of the string being printed may vary in your stored data. `strlen` will give you the length of your string without counting the terminating `\0` so there is no good way to know where a string ends once you've written it. I can't imagine how you plan on reading the string back in.

Comment: Your last comment saved me. I've made a mistake with the `strlen`.. What a noob...

Comment: It happens to the best of us, @Michael; I'm glad to have been of service.

Answer (score 3):

If you wrote a `struct` from a file, you should read a `struct` back; trying to read an `int` is not going to work. However, it rarely, if ever, makes sense two write out as binary a `struct` that contains pointers. You should either make them arrays of fixed size, or serialize them separately from your `struct`.

**EDIT :** (in response to posted code) Most likely the problem has to do with writing an unknown number of characters in the second call of `fwrite`. When you serialize a C string, you should write out the number of characters before writing the characters themselves, so that when you read you'd know how much characters to allocate and to read back:

```
int len = strlen(tmpA->a2);
fwrite(&len, sizeof(int), 1, file);    
fwrite(tmpA->a2, sizeof(char), len, file);
...
fread(&(tmpA->a1), sizeof(int), 1, file);
tmpA->a2 = malloc(tmpA->a1+1);
fread(tmpA->a2, sizeof(char), tmpA->a1, file);
tmpA->a2[tmpA->a1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am not writing the entire `struct` at once - I'm using multiple calls to `fwrite` for each of the `struct` members.

Comment: @Michael Seeing your `fread` and `fwrite` calls would be useful then.

Comment: I've posted the `fwrite` part, and the `fread` part is almost the same.

Comment: The first `int` in the `struct` is used for that exact purpose.

Comment: You should consider using more descriptive variable names, @Michael.

Comment: @Richard I'm sorry, the real code has descriptive var. names. Problem is that I can't just copy paste it... So I've made some shortcuts..

Comment: @Michael How do you read the second value then? Take a look at my last update, is that what you do?

Comment: Yep, this is how I did it.